# Which protocol to use for game communication between clients and server

Tags: c++, game-engine, marmalade

I need only advice or link to tutorial, I am making multiplayer RTS game and game is going to have intensive communication ( I am making client side using C++ and marmalade for crossplatform on ios/android). Which protocol should I use for communication (TCP, HTTP long polling- to avoid const sending requests to server, or websocket) ? Does anyone know good C++ library for websockets for ARM ?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but maybe this will help: http://www.codeofhonor.com/blog/choosing-a-game-network-lib

Comment: Don't you need server side support of websocket if you want to use it?

Comment: @tAmirNaghizadeh I have server side support for websockets through Tornado.

Comment: Did you come to a conclusion, or tried anything? It'd be nice to know your approach and experience

Comment: share your exprience if you can , what was your choice ?